# Getting the map bounds of a GeoJson region in leaflet prior to zooming

Tags: leaflet

I'm using leaflet and I'm loading up the regions of my map dynamically from a database, based on the bounding box coordinates of the currently viewed map. As I zoom in, the detail of each new layer increases. The same regions will exist in every layer of the map, and the same region on a different zoom level will have the same id.

I am currently attempting to calculate the target map bounds and target zoom level, so that I can load up all the intersecting regions within the new map bounding box. I currently have the following code.

```
zoomToFeature(e) {
    //e.g. map zoom for currently visible map is 3
    const layer = e.target;
    let padding = [5, 5];
    let layerBounds = layer.getBounds();
    
    //e.g layerBounds returns:
    //ne = lat: -37.770025, lng: 145.02439
    //sw = lat: -37.834451, lng: 144.900952

    let targetZoom = this.map.getBoundsZoom(layerBounds, false, padding);
    targetZoom = Math.min(this.map.getMaxZoom(), targetZoom);
    //e.g.targetZoom for this feature is 12

    let center = layer.getCenter()
    //e.g. center for this layer is lat: -37.78808138412046, lng: 144.93164062500003

    let targetPixelBounds = this.map.getPixelBounds(center, targetZoom);
    //e.g. targetPixelBounds: max: Point{x: 946751, y: 643578} min:{x:946114,y:643078}
    //this looks very wrong, and so causes everything below to fail I think.
    //am I supposed to reset the origin? am I meant to project the center and targetZoom?

    let sw = this.map.unproject(targetPixelBounds.getBottomLeft());
    let ne = this.map.unproject(targetPixelBounds.getTopRight());
    let targetMapBounds = new L.LatLngBounds(sw, ne);
    
    this.map.flyTo(center,targetZoom);

    this.loadMapData(targetMapBounds, targetZoom).subscribe(() => {
      
      this.removeOldRegions(); // deletes existing geojson
      this.loadRegions(); // adds retrieved data to new geojson layer
      //find the same region but in the new zoom layer
      let newLayer = this.getLayerById(layer.feature.properties.id);
      this.highlightFeature(newLayer);
    });
    
  }
```

It is going wrong at the
let targetPixelBounds = this.map.getPixelBounds(center, targetZoom)
line.

Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've cracked the case.

The unproject lines in the original code above take zoom level as an argument, which I didn't put in the original code.. So I've refactored the code, which I have posted below.

Basically once I have the map bounding box, I can perform the fly to, and execute code to retrieve the new geojson at the new zoom level. By the time the animation has completed, the new geojson layer is already loaded. (Written in TypeScript. Sorry non TypeScript people)

```
zoomToFeature(e) {
    const layer = e.target;
    let padding = [5, 5];
    let layerBounds = layer.getBounds();
    let targetMapBoundsZoom = this.getTargetMapBoundsZoom(layerBounds, { padding: padding });
    this.map.flyToBounds(targetMapBoundsZoom.bounds);
    this.loadMapData(targetMapBoundsZoom.bounds, targetMapBoundsZoom.zoom).subscribe(() => {
      this.removeOldRegions();
      this.loadRegions();
      //find the same region but in the new zoom layer
      let newLayer = this.getLayerById(layer.feature.properties.id);
      this.highlightFeature(newLayer);
    });
  }

  getTargetMapBoundsZoom(bounds, options) {
    let newBoundsCenterZoom = this._getBoundsCenterZoom(bounds, options);
    let targetMapBoundsPixels = this.map.getPixelBounds(newBoundsCenterZoom.center, newBoundsCenterZoom.zoom);
    let targetSw = this.map.unproject(targetMapBoundsPixels.getBottomLeft(), newBoundsCenterZoom.zoom);
    let targetNe = this.map.unproject(targetMapBoundsPixels.getTopRight(), newBoundsCenterZoom.zoom);
    let targetMapBounds = new L.LatLngBounds(targetSw, targetNe);
    return {
      bounds: targetMapBounds,
      zoom: newBoundsCenterZoom.zoom
    }
  }


loadMapData(bounds, zoom): Observable<any[]> {
    const boundingBox = Util.GetMapBounds(bounds);
    const regionTypeId = this.regionTypeIds[this._regionType];
    return this.mapService.getGeoJsonData("AU",
      regionTypeId,
      zoom,
      boundingBox.n,
      boundingBox.s,
      boundingBox.e,
      boundingBox.w).pipe(map((response: any) => {
        this.mapGeoJsonData = this.createFeatureCollection(response.data);
        return this.mapGeoJsonData;
      }));
  }

//this is a copy of the original _getBoundsCenterZoom that is internal to leaflet, with minor modifications.
_getBoundsCenterZoom(bounds, options) {
    
     options = options || {};
     bounds = bounds.getBounds ? bounds.getBounds() : L.latLngBounds(bounds);
    
     var paddingTL = L.point(options.paddingTopLeft || options.padding || [0, 0]),
         paddingBR = L.point(options.paddingBottomRight || options.padding || [0, 0]),
    
     zoom = this.map.getBoundsZoom(bounds, false, paddingTL.add(paddingBR));
     zoom = (typeof options.maxZoom === 'number') ? Math.min(options.maxZoom, zoom) : zoom;
    
     if (zoom === Infinity) {
        return {
           center: bounds.getCenter(),
           zoom: zoom
        };
     }
    
     var paddingOffset = paddingBR.subtract(paddingTL).divideBy(2),
     swPoint = this.map.project(bounds.getSouthWest(), zoom),
     nePoint = this.map.project(bounds.getNorthEast(), zoom),
     center = this.map.unproject(swPoint.add(nePoint).divideBy(2).add(paddingOffset), zoom);
    
     return {
       center: center,
       zoom: zoom
     };
}

createFeatureCollection(data: any) {
    let featureCollection = {
      type: "FeatureCollection",
      features: data.map(r => {
        const geoJson = JSON.parse(r.geoJson);
        if (geoJson.type === "GeometryCollection") {
          geoJson.geometries = geoJson.geometries.filter(r => r.type === "Polygon" || r.type === "MultiPolygon");
        }
        let feature = {
          type: "Feature",
          id: r.id,
          properties: { id: r.id },
          geometry: geoJson
        }
        return feature;
      })
    };
    return featureCollection;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

The default behaviour for this is to read out the bounds and pass it to the map:

```
map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
```

Then you function can look like:

```
zoomToFeature(e) {
    let padding = [5, 5];
    let layerBounds = e.target.getBounds();

    let targetZoom = this.map.getBoundsZoom(layerBounds, false, padding);
    targetZoom = Math.min(this.map.getMaxZoom(), targetZoom);
    //e.g.targetZoom for this feature is 12

    map.fitBounds(layerBounds , {padding: padding, maxZoom: targetZoom });
    
    this.loadMapData(layerBounds , targetZoom).subscribe(() => {      
      this.removeOldRegions(); // deletes existing geojson
      this.loadRegions(); // adds retrieved data to new geojson layer
      //find the same region but in the new zoom layer
      let newLayer = this.getLayerById(layer.feature.properties.id);
      this.highlightFeature(newLayer);
    });
}
```

this moves the map and zoom it to the layer.

Comment: That seems quite inefficient. It has to be executed before loading the new layer, and it didn't allow for the zoom animation.

Comment: Also, you can't use the layer bounds in the request to the database as that would only include regions within the layer bounds, which doesn't include the rest of the visible map. I need the map bounds, not the current clicked layer (region) bounds